# How to add only one marker in leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am adding marker on map on user click.
Problem is that I want only one marker but now whenever I click on map new marker is added.
I am trying to remove it but nothing happens:

```
var marker;
    map.on('click', function (e) {
        map.removeLayer(marker)

        marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, { draggable: true });
        marker.bindPopup("<strong>" + e.latlng + "</strong>").addTo(map);

        marker.on('dragend', markerDrag);
    });
```

Answer (score 24):

Instead of using `.on` to capture and handle the event, you could use `.once`. That way the event will be only captured once and the handler will unbind itself after that.

```
map.on('click', function () {
    console.log('I fire every click');
});

map.once('click', function () {
    console.log('I fire only once');
});
```

If you're ever need to unbind a handler yourself you can use `.off`. Check the reference for event methods: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events

As to why your code above isn't working, on first click you're trying remove the marker: `map.removeLayer(marker)`, but the variable `marker` doesn't contain a L.Marker instance so the map is unable to remove it. You should check if it's defined first and only then remove it:

```
var marker;
map.on('click', function (e) {
    if (marker) { // check
        map.removeLayer(marker); // remove
    }
    marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng); // set
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iEcivecU7HGajQqDWzVH?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Use [.off()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events) to unbind the on click event.

It should be something like:

```
var marker;
map.on('click', mapClicked);

function mapClicked(e) {
    map.off('click', mapClicked);
    map.removeLayer(marker)

    marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, { draggable: true });
    marker.bindPopup("<strong>" + e.latlng + "</strong>").addTo(map);

    marker.on('dragend', markerDrag);
}
```

I didn't test it but it should at least put you in the right direction.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for pulling in another library since Leaflet has it's own methods for binding and unbinding events: [http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events)