# leaflet remove specific marker

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, leaflet

I am very new to use Leaflet and its plugins. Currently I am working with a project to mark a specific location in the map with a marker.

But somehow I do not know how can I remove specific marker from the map if there are multiple markers.

Markers are bind to pop-ups with some information and a button in the box. Therefore, my aim here is to remove the specific marker after the button is clicked.

```
var popupContent =
    '<p>Some Infomation</p></br>' +
    '<p>' + date + '</p></br>' +
    '<button onclick=clearMarker()>Clear Marker</button>';

myMarker = L.marker([lat, lng], { icon: redMarker, draggable: false });
var myPopup = myMarker.bindPopup(popupContent, { closeButton: false });
map.addLayer(myMarker);
```

Please let me know if there any improvement in the way I add the markers (Pretty sure there is better way to achieve that).

Comment: I did tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609294/how-to-remove-marker-from-leaflet-map?rq=1) approach but it only delete the latest added markers instead of the specific marker added in earlier

Comment: I'm hoping you can answer this. I see in the solution below the removal of the data marker through the map.removeLayer, what about when you have all of your markers on a single layer, How can you remove a marker then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try with private properties, check on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmnjv78y/)

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var markers = []

function createMarker(coords) {
  var id
  if (markers.length < 1) id = 0
  else id = markers[markers.length - 1]._id + 1
  var popupContent =
    '<p>Some Infomation</p></br>' +
    '<p>test</p></br>' +
    '<button onclick="clearMarker(' + id + ')">Clear Marker</button>';
  myMarker = L.marker(coords, {
    draggable: false
  });
  myMarker._id = id
  var myPopup = myMarker.bindPopup(popupContent, {
    closeButton: false
  });
  map.addLayer(myMarker)
  markers.push(myMarker)
}

function clearMarker(id) {
  console.log(markers)
  var new_markers = []
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    if (marker._id == id) map.removeLayer(marker)
    else new_markers.push(marker)
  })
  markers = new_markers
}
createMarker([51.5, -0.09])
createMarker([51.5, -0.093])
createMarker([51.5, -0.096])
```

Comment: Thanks [Sebastian Schulz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8528471/sebastian-schulz) for your patience. I managed to solve that by assigning an ID to the button (ID is same as the index of the marker in that array) and push the marker to the array. On the click on button, the ID will be check the id and remove the particular layer. Then callback to splice the marker from the array.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some input on this too. I see in the solution the removal of the data marker through the map.removeLayer, what about when you have all of your markers on a single layer, How can you remove a marker then?