# How to delete my map markers in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, markers

I just can't delete my markers. I have tried all the pages here already. But it seems my knowledge is too limited.

Is the problem that I don't add the markers to a `layerGroup` the right way?

```
var markers = [];
var layerGroup;

function makeMap(inputData){
  layerGroup = L.layerGroup(markers).addTo(map);
}

function handleLayer(layer){
  markers.push(L.marker(layer.feature.properties.koordinater, {icon: L.divIcon({ className: 'css-icon', html: value, iconSize: [50, 1] })}));
}

function deleteMarkers(){       
  layerGroup.clearLayers(map);
}
```

Comment: See other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609294/how-to-remove-marker-from-leaflet-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the wrong function in `deleteMarkers`. This should help:

```
function deleteMarkers() {
    layerGroup.clearLayers();
}
```

EDIT

According to the comments in the comment section `layerGroup.clearLayers()` solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i cant get that too work either.

Comment: *YaFred
I got it now, thanks for all help.
layerGroup.clearLayers(); was the right answer.
I had some nesting done wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to end up with in your variables - you could use

`map.removeLayer(layerGroup)`

which preserves the layerGroup if you might need to add it back again.